# Translate Entity Framework Core Example to F#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, f#

I'm trying to translate the example [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/index) to F# but I can't translate the `BloggingContext`class.

Until now I wrote

```
type BloggingContext() =
inherit DbContext()

member val Blogs = DbSet<Blog>() with get,set
member val Posts = DbSet<Post>() with get,set
```

which is incomplete and Visual Studio Code complains that DbSet has no accessible object constructors. Besides that, I don't know how to override the method `OnConfiguring`.

Answer (score 6):

I used the Fyodor's answer but later when I try to add a new Blog to the set I receive a null reference exception. So, the answer I found is to modify the declarations of `Blogs` and `Posts` to be:

```
[<DefaultValue>] val mutable m_blogs : DbSet<Blog>
    member public this.Blogs with get() = this.m_blogs 
                                        and set v = this.m_blogs <- v

[<DefaultValue>] val mutable m_posts : DbSet<Post>
    member public this.Posts with get() = this.m_posts 
                                        and set v = this.m_posts <- v
```

The `override` keyword solution worked fine for me!

Answer (score 5):

Since `DbSet<T>` has no public constructors, you can't create instances of it yourself. The idea was that you would just declare properties with `null` as initial value, and EF will assign new values to them later. So you can just specify the initial value of `null`, that should do it:

```
member val Blogs: DbSet<Blog> = null with get,set
```

To override a method, use the `override` keyword:

```
override this.OnConfiguring optionsBuilder =
   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

Comment: I used this solution but I found another problem later. When I create a new `BloggingContext` instance the member Blogs are not instantiated by `DbSet` so when I try to add a new Blog I receive a `System.NullReferenceException`.

Comment: FSharp Properties [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/properties) actually warns against this: There are some libraries, such as the Entity Framework (System.Data.Entity) that perform custom operations in base class constructors that don't work well with the initialization of automatically implemented properties. In those cases, try using explicit properties.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, it not equivalent code, but it works the same and is considerably shorter that the accepted answer:

```
type BloggingContext() =
  inherit DbContext()

  member this.Blogs: DbSet<Blog> = this.Set()
  member this.Posts: DbSet<Post> = this.Set()
```

I'm not sure if it worked with every EF Core version, but it works just fine with version 6.0.0